# Apache Http server has stopped working after installing and configuring magento 2

Tags: apache, magento2

I have resolved all the port related issues for localhost but it is still not working, if i run wordpress site or any other site it works perfectly fine.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.23.0
  Application Timestamp:    577631b1
  Fault Module Name:    libapr-1.dll
  Fault Module Version: 1.5.2.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5776333f
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0001828d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 4572
  Additional Information 2: 45724fc51e19b241d9ad2502b711af8a
  Additional Information 3: 4dcb
  Additional Information 4: 4dcb8c69e842378bd8a21150aac79161

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: Please share some details of the error, or what 'is not working' means more precisely.

Comment: I think it's just how magento works on Windows - I get it for magento 1 too on Windows only, maybe a combo of how apache works (single threading) and how windows uses the hardware

Comment: I installed and configured magento2.x on localhost. when I try to open front end or back end of magento, I get an error that apache http server has stopped working. I also mentioned error signature above –